# Should I call Parameters.Clear when reusing a SqlCommand with a transation?

Tags: c#, ado.net, transactions, named-parameters

I'm coding a transaction manually in ADO.NET.  The example I'm working from reuses the `SqlCommand` which seem like a fine idea.

However, I have added parameters to my command.

My question is: in the following code, is `command.Parameters.Clear()` correct?  Or am I doing it wrong?

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(EomAppCommon.EomAppSettings.ConnStr))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = transaction;
    try
    {
        foreach (var itemIDs in this.SelectedItemIds)
        {
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Item SET payment_method_id = @batchID WHERE id in (@itemIDs)";
            // IS THE FOLLOWING CORRECT?
            command.Parameters.Clear();

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@batchID", batchID));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@itemIDs", itemIDs));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to update payment batches, rolling back." + ex.Message);
        try
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception exRollback)
        {
            if (!(exRollback is InvalidOperationException)) // connection closed or transaction already rolled back on the server.
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to roll back. " + exRollback.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just create the command inside the loop? Or create an SQL statement that can do all of the updates in one go, and avoid the loop entirely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you're repeatedly executing the same query, it's unnecessary to clear them - you can add the parameters outside the loop and just fill them inside.

```
try
{
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE Item SET payment_method_id = @batchID WHERE id in (@itemIDs)";
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@batchID", 0));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@itemIDs", ""));

    foreach (var itemIDs in this.SelectedItemIds)
    {
        command.Parameters["@batchID"].Value = batchID;
        command.Parameters["@itemIDs"].Value = itemIDs;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Note - [you can't use parameters with IN as you've got here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause) - it won't work.

Comment: yeah I just discovered that about the IN clause, thanks for the link

Comment: Besides the additional processing, is there any other downside to clearing and re-adding them? Not clearing them also makes the code less DRY.

Answer (score 1):

In this condition you need it as you need set new parameters values, so its correct.

By the way, move

```
command.CommandText = ".."
```

outside of the loop too, as it's never changed.