# How to add more than one record adding in to database from datagridview c#

Tags: c#

I tried the code below but I could add one row record only added in to mysql database. I entered three rows records but only one row records only added. What is the problem?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
      cmd.Connection = con;

      cmd.CommandText = "insert into salesproductnew(salesid,productname,qty,price,grosstotal)values(@salesid,@productname,@qty,@price,@grosstotal)";


      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesid", lbinvoice.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);

      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      MessageBox.Show("Record added .............");
      con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: wrap the code with try..catch and see if you have an exception

Comment: no exception i got it. no errors. only one row record only added in the database what happening another records please fix this problem

Comment: any one help me?

Comment: How many message boxes do you see?

Comment: i tried it dosen't works

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting parameters of your `cmd`, you are adding new parameters on each cycle. May not be direct answer, but try this

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into salesproductnew(salesid,productname,qty,price,grosstotal)values(@salesid,@productname,@qty,@price,@grosstotal)";
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salesid", lbinvoice.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grosstotal", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}

  MessageBox.Show("Record added .............");
  con.Close();
```

Btw, You do not have to clear parameters. see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14374630/2892829) for more info.

Comment: not error i could added one row record in to database. more than one record i couldn't added... please help me

Comment: Is `salesid` unique or primary key? You should receive some error. assign `var recordsAdded = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and try to debug it.

Comment: salesid unique key sir. var record =  cmdadd.ExecuteNonQuery(); i tried one row only record added

Comment: `lbinvoice.Text` is not changing inside `for` loop. You cannot insert multiple rows with same unique key. Add another field as primary key(if not exists) and mark `salesid` as non-unique.

Comment: then how to write this code. can you modify the code and write it

Comment: just modify it on your database

Comment: what sort of the thing am i going to modify in the database

Comment: you can refer to [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3487726/2892829) for how tu remove unique index